# Flex 3: Getting error of "Parse error at '<mx:ComboBox>'>." What does it mean?

Tags: apache-flex, parsing, combobox

```
<mx:List columnCount="5" rowCount="11" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{parentDocument.crewPositionsAC}" useRollOver="false" alternatingItemColors="[0xffffff, 0xe5e5e5]" borderStyle="none">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:Text text="{data}" color="#840021" selectable="false" />
            <mx:ComboBox id="studentType">
                <mx:ArrayCollection>
                    <mx:String>BFA1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>BFA2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>BFA3</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA3</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw3</mx:String>
                </mx:ArrayCollection>
            </mx:ComboBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

When I try to save it, I get the error:

> Parse error at '<mx:ComboBox>'.

Anybody able to see what's causing the error?

Comment: Instead `alternatingItemColors="[0xffffff, 0xe5e5e5]"` Try using data binding: `alternatingItemColors="{[0xffffff, 0xe5e5e5]}"`

Comment: Why?  What's the advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: I thought it might be your problem. Well apparently it isn't! Nevertheless within the curly braces it is much more clearer that you instantiate an array, but since the style property handles it just fine like you originally wrote it, then you can just ignore my suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have a single component defined as an in-line itemRenderer.  You have two defined, a Text and a ComboBox.  The solution is to wrap them up in a container.  I used an HBox for the purposes of demonstration.

```
<mx:List columnCount="5" rowCount="11" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{parentDocument.crewPositionsAC}" useRollOver="false" alternatingItemColors="[0xffffff, 0xe5e5e5]" borderStyle="none">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
           <mx:HBox>
            <mx:Text text="{data}" color="#840021" selectable="false" />
            <mx:ComboBox id="studentType">
                <mx:ArrayCollection>
                    <mx:String>BFA1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>BFA2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>BFA3</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFA3</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw1</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw2</mx:String>
                    <mx:String>MFAw3</mx:String>
                </mx:ArrayCollection>
            </mx:ComboBox>
           </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just threw a "<mx:Canvas>" around it and it worked :D